# sed- delete line that doesn't contain a pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I'm surprised that I can't find a question similar to this one on SO.

How do I use sed to delete all lines that do not contain a specific pattern.

For example, I have this file:

```
cat kitty dog
giraffe panda
lion tiger
```

I want a sed command that, when called, will delete all lines that do not contain the word `cat`:

```
cat kitty dog
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do:

```
sed -i '/cat/!d' file1.txt
```

To force an exact match:

```
sed -i '/\<cat\>/!d' file1.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '/\bcat\b/!d' file1.txt
```

where `\<\>` & `\b\b` force an exact match.

Comment: Also, `sed -n '/cat/p'`

Comment: Try that on input that contains the word `scatter`. Is that the desired behavior?

Answer (score 6):

So your requirement would be "give me all lines containing string `cat`". then why not just simply using `grep` :

```
grep cat file
```

Answer (score 2):

to see all lines containg word 'cat' (as pointed by Kent):

```
grep cat file
```

to see all lines NOT containg word 'cat':

```
grep -v cat file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '/cat/' file
```